# How to determine where an environment variable is set on a MAC

Tags: macos, mac

I am on a mac and I previously installed and JENKINS_HOME=/user/myusername/Jenkins but now I did a fresh install.  the plist for for jenkins is /User/Shared/Jenkins/Home and yet the app is looking for the war expaned at old JENKINS_HOME  /user/myusername/Jenkins which is not what I want. How to i reset the JENKINS_HOME.  I mean the plist already tells it not to go there but it does anyway.  Frankly in general I do not know where to go to reset environment variables like this. When I echo the environment variable I don't see it pointing to anything.  But when I try to startup jenkins it uses this old value.

Basically the error I am getting is that it cant find manifest in /users/myuser/Jenkins/war/Manifest.xml etc

And it says just before JENKINS_HOME="/user/myuser/jenkins yet the plist says otherwise. perhaps I also need to pass this in as an argument?

Comment: What do you mean by fresh install? And what is the plist? I don't know Jenkins, but knowing that would help.

Answer (score 1):

You can define JENKINS_HOME virtually everywhere. That makes it a bit hard.

But the best guess I can make is the following:
As you deploy the WAR-file I assume that you are using apaches tomcat or something equivalentas servlet-engine. Therefore I would have a look into the config-files for the tomcat. In my installation I have a file called `startup.sh` in tomcats `bin`-folder where I defined the `JENKINS_HOME`.

The last way to find it would be a brute-force method by using a Terminal and running `grep -R JENKINS_HOME /` which will search for the term `JENKINS_HOME` in **EVERY** file on the machine.

**BE warned!! This might take some time!!**